# Checking SQL Syntax Against MariaDB Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am converting a series of databases to reference MariaDB instead of using SQL Anywhere. Since there are some minor syntax differences between these two, I'd like to check that my existing SQL statements will work with MariaDB. Is there an online resource one can use to do this? I found this SQL syntax checker: https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/ -- but I'm not sure if also covers MariaDB syntax?

If not, I'll have compile a manual checklist of syntax differences, like this:

```
TOP [INT] at beginning of a SELECT query is now a LIMIT [INT] at the end of a SELECT query.

COUNT() is now COUNT(*)

(column + ' ' + column) is now CONCAT(column, ' ', column)

DATEADD(unit, num, datetime) is now TIMESTAMPADD(unit, num, datetime)

DATEDIFF(unit, num, datetime) is now TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit, num, datetime)
```

Comment: I would not trust ANY SQL checker. The only way to be sure is going to be the hard way.

Comment: Your checklist will probably become a hundred lines long.  Furthermore, the list will have many incomplete suggestions, since some differences are not as simple as a simple substitution.  This Comment applies to translating from any vendor to any other vendor.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check the syntax is to run your commands on a MariaDB test database.